# Proof of Weyl Character formula for $sl_n\mathbb{C}$

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there a proof of Weyl character formula just for $sl_n\mathbb{C}$ independent of any 'heavy machinery'? Please suggest some references if possible.

Comment: Yes, in particular for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, see page $5$ [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/mat445/WCF.pdf).

Comment: Seems like it uses Weyl character formula and gives a consequence of that in case of $sl_2\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes, that's right. But then one has an easy version for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, which can be proved directly without heavy machinery.